# Check to see if an array is contained within another array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

The problem is: Check to see if the array arr2 is contained within the arr1 in the same order. The arr2 could be contained anywhere with in arr1.

```
public boolean contains(String[] arr1, String[] arr2)
{
   int length  = 0;
   if(arr2.length > arr1.length)
      return false;
   for(int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++)
   {
      if(arr2[i] == arr1[i])
          length++;
   }
   if(length == arr2.length)
      return true;
   else
      return false;
}
```

TESTER: contains({"1", "2", "3"}, {"1", "2"}) → true

RUN: TRUE

TESTER: contains({"1", "2", "3"}, {"2", "3"}) → true

RUN: FALSE

TESTER: contains({"1", "2", "3"}, {"2", "1"}) → false

RUN: TRUE

TESTER: contains({"MARY", "A", "LITTLE", "LAMB"}, {"A", "LITTLE", "LAMB"}) → true

RUN: FALSE

TESTER: contains({"MARY", "A", "LITTLE", "LAMB"}, {"MARY", "A", "LITTLE", "LAMB"}) → true

RUN: TRUE

.

I don't know where I'm going wrong. Thanks for help.

Comment: Hint: you need a nested for loop.

Comment: @mdnghtblue: Actually, you don't, though it can certainly be done that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- use `arr[1].equals(arr[2])` instead `arr[1] == arr[2]`
- should judge in the loop not before loop

I modify the code like it:

```
public static boolean contains(String[] arr1, String[] arr2) {
    int length = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        if (arr2[length].equals(arr1[i])) {
            length++;
        } else {
            length = 0;
        }
        if (length == arr2.length)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only comparing both arrays from the beginning; you need to also consider the cases when you start comparing at a different location in `arr1`.  For example, you would get TRUE in the second example if you started comparing at the second element of `arr1` (same for the fourth example).

Comment: So how do I start comparing at the second element of arr1? I tried at the if statement to do `if(arr2[i] == arr1[i] || arr2[i] == arr1[i+1])` but it doens't work.